# BB Webworks exception ('javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException') while buiding the app

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I need some help here. It´s related with Blackberry WebWorks plataform.

I´m running Ripple chrome extension for my dynamic web project. I´ve make the steps showed here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/packaging_your_app_in_ripple_1904611_11.html

but I get this error when building the app from 'Package & Sign' button in the Chrome extension.

If you want any extra information let me know.

Thank you!

```
out: [INFO]
out: Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.

out: C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\lib\net
_rim_api.jar(net_rim_jaxrpc.cod): Error!: Duplicate definition for 'javax.xml.rp
c.JAXRPCException' found in: JAXRPCException.java

out: [ERROR]
out: RAPC exception occurred

Done build
```

Comment: Seems you have two methods called main this cause the java exception in build time. can you check that?

Comment: it may seem strange but i dont have any method called main... It may be from some lib which are being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually the result of building with the -s flag (which produces the Java source for the app) and then having this source contained in your zip. The source files are what provide the duplicate java files.

Ripple automatically zips the entire directory of your web app, so please clean the directory of any extra files and try again.

Comment: thank you, it was that, I just take the files to other place without the Webinfo folders and it worked!

Comment: Can I use as content an index.jsp instead a index.html? When I do it it says: "The returned page have not content and so it cant be proccessed"

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check.

1. Make sure you're using JDK 1.6
2. You must be using the 32-Bit version.